# Android Studio 3.2.1 - NDK r10e sync fail?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I have a project created by `Android Studio version 3.1.3` and Gradle `version 4.4.1`. It contains some native code and runs well with `NDK r10e`. Yesterday I upgraded my `Android Studio to version 3.2.1` (it required `Gradle version 4.6` so I updated it on Gradle wrapper too). But after the upgrade process done, `Gradle` sync fails with this error :

> **Parameter specified as non-null is null:** method
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.JsonGenerationVariantConfiguration.,
>   parameter ndkVersion

My `NDK` location still points to my `NDK r10e` directory. I can not change it to a higher `NDK` version because it will occur many other errors.

What should I do? Please help.

Comment: Clinging to a 3.5 years old version of the NDK because you're encountering some errors when upgrading doesn't seem like a solution in the long term. You should go through each of those errors and fix them.

Comment: @Michael : thank for your advice. But my project used a custom cocos framework, that are used by many projects in the company I'm working for. So I have no choice to use other or upgrade it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a hard time because of this problem. The solution was surprisingly simple.

1. Download NDK version 11 or higher
2. Copy the source.properties from the downloaded NDK root folder and paste it into the NDK r10e folder
3. Modify the source.properties Pkg.Revision to match the x.y.z format (optional)

Comment: I used version r12b and this solved my problems. In the NDK folder there should be a source.properties . inside that there is a few things that MUST exist. Pkg.Desc = Android NDK
Pkg.Revision = 12.1.2977051

Of course make sure your local.properties points to this location too.